# convert string to required timestamp format in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, oracle12c

From the frontend I am getting a string in this format:

```
2020-10-15 0:34:51. 751000000
```

I want to insert it as a timestamp in oracle. But I am unable to insert as I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

I have checked my nls and database timestamp format is

```
DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SSXFF AM
```

Is there a way to convert the above mentioned string to required timestamp format in oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the following format specifier:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss ff'
```

You can convert your string to a `timestamp` with `to_timestamp()`:

```
select to_timestamp('2020-10-15 0:34:51. 751000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss ff') ts from dual
```

In [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9249c2f2cd667d339cecb0eb293028d2), where the timestamp format is set to  `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssff'`, the query returns:

```
| TS                           |
| :--------------------------- |
| 2020-10-15 00:34:51751000000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    '2020-10-15 0:34:51. 751000000',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS. FF9'
  )
);
```

Or, use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
VALUES ( TIMESTAMP '2020-10-15 0:34:51. 751000000' );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=914ad610c968013e67bf4438575fb324)*